# How do I get my linked list to display on one line and not create a new line each time? C++

Tags: c++

So I need help on making the program display the linked list in only one line with nothing in between them. I also need to the use _getch(), getch() or getchar() functions not cin or something similar, the current program uses the _getch() function.

I'll provide my code, output and desired output.
Thank you for the help in advance.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct Node {
    std::string data{};
    Node* next{ nullptr };
};

void addToList(Node*& head, Node*& tail) {
    bool quit{ false };
    std::string temp{};
    Node* current{ nullptr };

    while (!quit) {
        temp = _getch();

        if (temp == "quit") {
            std::cout << "\tQuitting submenu.\n";
            quit = true;
        }
        else {
            // Allocate the new node here
            current = new Node;
            current->data = temp;

            if (tail) {

                tail->next = current;
                tail = current;
            }
            else {
                head = current;
                tail = current;
            }

            std::stringstream ss;
            for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
            ss << current->data;
            }

            std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "|" << std::setw(12) << ss.str() << "|" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    bool quit = false;
    int choice = 0;
    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;

    while (!quit) {
        std::cout << "1. add to list, 2. quit:\n";
        std::cin >> choice;
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            addToList(head, tail);
            break;
        case 2:
            std::cout << "Quitting main menu.\n";
            quit = true;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "That is not a valid input, quitting program.\n";
            quit = true;
        }
    }
    for (auto tmp{ head }; tmp;) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
        delete head;
        head = tmp;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
+------------+
|           3|
+------------+

+------------+
|         334|
+------------+

+------------+
|      334345|
+------------+

+------------+
|  3343453456|
+------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------------+
|           3|
+------------+

+------------+
|          34|
+------------+

+------------+
|         345|
+------------+

+------------+
|        3456|
+------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create the string you want to print first using a `std::stringstream`, then print it on a single line, like this:

```cpp
std::stringstream ss;
for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
    ss << current->data;
}

std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl;
std::cout << "|" << std::setw(12) << ss.str() << "|" << std::endl;
std::cout << "+------------+" << std::endl << std::endl;
```

instead of this, which prints one line per list entry

```cpp
cout << "+------------+" << endl;
for (current = head; current; current = current->next) {
    std::cout << "|" << std::setw(12) << current->data << (current->next ? "" : "") << "|" << endl;
}
cout << "+------------+" << "\n\n";
```

Remember to add `#include <sstream>` at the top too.

Comment: I get an error using the std::stringstream ss; saying incomplete type is not allowed and the ss is underlined in red, the << is ss << current->data; underlined read and ss.str() is underlined red.

Comment: Did you add `#include <sstream>`?

Comment: No haven't, thank you but now it is printing the old output with the other one

Comment: Like so, +------------+
|           1|
+------------+

+------------+
|         112|
+------------+

+------------+
|      112123|
+------------+  Sorry for the formatting in the comments

Comment: Did you replace the old code with this, or just add this in addition?

Comment: I put this on top of where it was in the old code

Comment: You need to replace the writer code you had before with this. I put in the question what part to replace (the "instead of this") code.

Comment: What a writer code?

Comment: The code you had in there to write the output before (the "cout" calls in `addToList`).

Comment: I changed the code in the question to the new code

Comment: Ok, can you put the formatted output you are getting with the new code in the question too then (update the "Output" section)?

Comment: Done, should I move this discussion to the discussion chat?

Comment: Nvm, I found the problem

Comment: What was it? Was `ss` actually declared outside your loop?

Comment: I changed the code, from when I posted it to have a char to avoid spaces in the program

Comment: Your solution worked thank you. It's because I added this to the code:

Comment: c = _getch();

            if (c == '\t' || c == '\n' || c == '\r' || c == ' ') continue;

            temp = temp + c;

Comment: Do you have any idea how to remove spaces as a input using _getch() with having a char?

Comment: Depends how you're using it - probably worth a separate question though.

Comment: nvm, i fixed it by clearing temp after it prints using temp = "";